# Anti - virus : How an antivirus checks a file infected by virus?

Tags: antivirus

I searched for working of an anti virus?
but could not got satisfactory answer ..  except that
1) it goes through dictionary based approach in which any suspicious code matched with some entry in database is reported for an action to the use
or
2) it follows the harmful activities of a process eg.then terminates it if file deletes some critical files for the stability of the system

**when a pen drive is inserted to a computer then exactly how an antivirus detects a virus or a file infected by virus ? and at which layer antivirus scans the files ? **

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Your question is not specifically about programming. You might find some more helpful information at the SuperUser site, such as [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/32304/virus-protection-for-flash-drives) and [this other question](http://superuser.com/questions/418438/protecting-usb-flash-drive-against-viruses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, **antivirus software scans files when they are written to disk**.

Here is an example that compares two approaches to reading an email attachment:

1. If a user views an email and clicks to open an attachment, there will usually be a prompt to save the attachment, or to just open it right away without saving it. This is how many users get viruses on their machines. If they click to open the attachment without saving it, the antivirus doesn't have an opportunity to scan the file.
2. On the other hand, if the user saves the file first, then the
   antivirus can scan it.

Some security software performs other checks besides just file saving. But this is basically how antivirus works.

In the case of the pen drive, the antivirus may not scan the files (unless the user directs it to do so), because the files have already been saved. However, some antivirus software will react to this event (attaching a new device) and catch the virus.

Comment: when they are accessed on the disk.